# Dynamic URLs in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to get URLs like /user/bob user/martin dynamically in CodeIgniter?

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 7):

You need to set up custom routing for the controller in application/config/routes.php, e.g.

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/user_controller_method/$1";
```

Answer (score 4):

you should use the

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/user_controller_method/$1";
```

as James suggested, and then define the funcion on the user controller:

```
function user_controller_method($username) {
   // ... $username should be the url param
}
```